# Can't repair boot?

Tags: boot, dpkg

Somehow grub can't boot into my Ubuntu installation, so I made a live USB and installed boot repair, which found the problem and then I tried to repair it with the command it gave me (sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3" dpkg --configure -a) but when I try to use it in Terminal, it gives me an error, saying "dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory"
What do I do wrong?

Comment: Use boot-repair

Comment: I used it and it gave me the command that I copy-pasted into the terminal and thats the error it gives me

Comment: Then you post the summary report it gives or re-run report and post link so someone can review your configuration.

Comment: It literally says to copy paste that command and then close it, and the error is just that line I wrote down in my question

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same problem. In my case I installed windows 10 (ltsc) and had deleted the KDE Neon grub (both on separate hard drives, and separated partition tables, Windows in GPT and linux in MBR ). When trying to do the same, download Boot repair, put it in UEFI to make it work, and then put the recommended one:
*Dpkg-error detected. Please open a terminal then type (or copy-paste) the following command:*

```
  sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/..." dpkg --configure -a
  
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: no such file or directory.
```

Well, I spent a few days looking for the solution. I have come to the conclusion that either it is very difficult to fix it and only the experts can (because there does not seem to be anyone who has published it), or it is a problem of Boot repair that its developers must solve. So I recommend to fix the grub in another way, (which I got here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing):

From a live CD:

```
Sudo apt-get update
```

So there are no dangers or so it says.

```
sudo apt-get purge grub-common
```

To delete the grub and its files, to be able to install another one that detects our GNU/linux

-As we are on a live CD so we use the commands to install it from there.

```
 "sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt"
```

Where **X** is the disk and **Y** is the partition (you can see where your GNU / Linux is from: *sudo fdisk -l*), it must be the partition where you have installed the ***/***  file. If you made a */boot* partition, then it should go to the end, as an example:

```
example: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/boot
```

And then we install it.

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX
```

Where **X** is the disk.
(if you have a "sudo: grub-install: command not found" in the terminal, you need install grub: "sudo apt-get install grub-pc")

-Now we can restart and enter the grub. In my case I enter the grub rescue. Black background, white letters and commands, then I access from there. (if you have more than one disk, you must select where is your grub) (If you want for more information consult: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#grub.3E)

```
ls
```

To view devices and partitions as (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) ...
I am looking for my partition ***/*** in one of those, (I remembered the size that I assigned when I made the partitions) you will have to find the way, either by size or by ext format, or some other.

```
ls (hdX,msdosY)
      
ls (hdX,msdosZ)

...
```

When I find my partition (hd**X**,msdos**A**) then:

```
set boot=(hdX,msdosA)
  
set prefix=(hdX,msdosA)/boot/grub
  
normal insmod
  
normal
```

I can go to the grub now and then I can access GNU/Linux from there.

-Once inside, it's time to reinstall the grub:

```
 sudo apt-get update
  
 sudo apt-get purge grub-common
  
 sudo apt-get install grub-pc
  
 sudo update grub
```

- It should be at that time, at least that's how it was for me. Since I had not installed Windows 10 with a /boot partition for it, my grub did not detect it, but I can access it from the boot selector in my BIOS. Hope it helps someone in my same situation, good luck. Strength and honor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe your live-USB doesn't has admin access use the **live Boot-Repair USB**

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I tried it before live ubuntu usb, and neither this can do it, goves the same error

Answer (score 0):

I feel for you! I spent some time today with Boot Repair and a configuration line similar to yours involving dpkg --configure -a. However, by luck or good fortune, it finally worked. My advice (lamentable as it is) is to be patient and keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix that worked for me:

```
sudo -s
```

Then:

```
chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/..."
dpkg --configure -a
```

Guessing `dpkg` is not running with the correct Auth.